# Passing a pointer as an parameter, memory usage

Tags: c, pointers, memory

i have a question concerning pointers.

What is the difference between these 2 options when it comes to memory usage. I've tried both and nothing has changed when it comes to my memory. I thought that the first would receive a pointer to the adress of the allocated memory, and the second would receive a copy.

```
    check_ret = check_tetrimino(&grid, *curr, ind_y, ind_x);
```

```
int         check_tetrimino(char ***grid, t_tetrimino curr, int ind_y, int ind_x)
```

or

```
    check_ret = check_tetrimino(grid, *curr, ind_y, ind_x);
```

```
int         check_tetrimino(char **grid, t_tetrimino curr, int ind_y, int ind_x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pointer in both cases. `char ***` is a pointer, and so is `char **`, and both have the same size:

```
sizeof(char**) == sizeof(char***)
```

So the amount of bytes copied for the two different function calls is the same in both cases. Obviously the pointers that the function receives point to different things, but this doesn't change the size of the function parameters.

Comment: Does it receive a copy tho? or does it simply point to the same piece of memory?

Comment: @Dave It receives a pointer. What it points to doesn't matter. Only a pointer is copied, which is always the same size.

Comment: Exactly. It could change when you're passing a pointer to bigger objects (`obj*` instead of `obj**`). I wonder why the -1 though...